# How do I call a function from another js file in a POST?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call

```
function sendMessageToUser(message, user)
```

which is in a function.js file, I already have the function working, I just put one line of it for reference.

I also have a web.js file, which has app.post's in there, which I want the function to be called in.

```
app.post("/web/suggest_oncall", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.user.name + " wants to suggest " + req.body.user + " as the next on call for the " + req.query.position + " positon " + "of the " + req.query.list + " team.");
    res.send("Hi.");
    sendMessageToUser("hi", req.body.user);
    console.log("Sending SMS to " + req.body.user);
});
```

It logs to the coneome sendMessageToUser isn't defined, how can I get it to recognize that function?

Comment: It depends on the scope of the function you're trying to call... which  is not clear from the code you've provided..

Comment: @TilwinJoy where would the scope be? I'm fairly new

Comment: If you simply define the functions in script they'll be under window object, referred to as global scope. If you defined any of the function inside another function that functions scope will be inside the parent function only.
BTW make sure the file containing `sendMessageToUser();` is loaded before the file  having post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export sendMessageToUser from function.js by putting something like this at the end:

```
module.exports = {
    sendMessageToUser: sendMessageToUser
};
```

Then you can import the function module in web.js by putting this at the top:

```
functions = require("./function");
```

And then sendMessageToUser is accessible as `functions.sendMessageToUser`.

`require("./function")` returns the value of `module.exports` in the JS file `function.js`.